# Multiple Chart Creation Series Overload

Tags: vba, excel

I am running into a problem when creating multiple charts from my vast range of data. I need to create 4 separate charts. After successfully creating the first chart my code for the next charts is similar, but the code produces an ungodly amount of series in the following charts. My 2nd chart has a total of 6 series, 3rd chart has 33 series, and my 4th has 48. In my data selection for each chart column B is my date, and then the second range is my data, but in my 2-4 charts the code starts selecting columns I have not specified.  How do I work around/fix that?

My Sub for creating these charts:

```
Sub ChartC()


Dim EmbChart As Chart, EmbChart1 As Chart, EmbChart2 As Chart, EmbChart3 As 
Chart
Dim cht As Object
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

For Each wks In Worksheets

If wks.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
  wks.ChartObjects.Delete
End If
Next wks


With Application.ActiveSheet
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With


'Cement Inventory Graph
Set EmbChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=2760, Width:=1000, 
Top:=150, Height:=400).Chart


With EmbChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("TestSheet_Const_Ktonnage").Range("B5:C" & LastRow)
    .Type = xlLine
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Year Overview of Total Cement Inventory"
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Total Cement Inventory"
End With


'Clinker Inventory Graph
Set EmbChart1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=2760, Width:=1000, Top:=650, Height:=400).Chart


With EmbChart1
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range("B5:B" & LastRow, "H5:H" & LastRow)
    .Type = xlLine
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Year Overview of Clinker Inventory"
End With


'Operational Efficiency Kiln1
 Set EmbChart2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=2760, Width:=1000, Top:=1150, Height:=400).Chart


With EmbChart2
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range("B5:B" & LastRow, "AI5:AI" & LastRow)
    .Type = xlLine
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Year Overview of Operational Efficiency For Kiln1"
End With


'Operational Efficiency Kiln2
Set EmbChart3 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=2760, Width:=1000, Top:=1650, Height:=400).Chart


With EmbChart3
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range("B5:B" & LastRow, "AX5:AX" & LastRow)
    .Type = xlLine
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Year Overview of Clinker Inventory"
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You program not-adjacent columns using a comma-delimited range. So instead of giving `Range` two arguments, give it one comma-delimited range argument:

```
Source:=Range("B5:B" & LastRow & "," & "AI5:AI" & LastRow)
```

so if LastRow is 150 this reduces to

```
Source:=Range("B5:B150,AI5:AI150")
```

Hope that helps

Comment: You are an absolute BOSSSSSS! Thank you! You fix it.